# opencv - background thread blocks UI thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, c++11, background

This program should allow the user to draw on the picture for few seconds(like preprocessing) and after that do some processing on the picture with ability to draw.

I create background thread to pause processing for some time. The user should be able to draw in that time.

The `while` loop is processing. 
Variable `running` shows if processing is active or the user can draw.

But in the code I wrote background thread blocks UI thread, although, as to my knowledge, they do not interact.

*This seems like `std::this_thread::sleep_for` blocks all threads, but documentation says it only blocks its thread. I do not know what that means.*

**How to not block all threads from current thread?**

**UPDATE:** This is a MCVE from interactive image segmentation. 
The program processes image in background and shows it in GUI.
But before processing starts I want the user to be able to click on GUI to help the algorithm.

At the moment preprocessing runs(no background, user can click, it will draw), the GUI stops and waits for processing to start(until background thread finishes).

```
#include <thread>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

bool running;
cv::Mat image;

void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void*)
{
    running = false;
    if (event == cv::EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        cv::circle(image, cv::Point(x, y), 20, cv::Vec3b(0, 0, 255), CV_FILLED);
        cv::imshow("window", image);
        cv::waitKey(1);
    }
    running = true;
}

int main()
{
    running = false;

    image = cv::Mat(400, 400, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0));
    cv::namedWindow("window", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cv::imshow("window", image);
    cv::waitKey(1);

    cv::setMouseCallback("window", onMouse);

    std::thread task = std::thread([]()
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
        running = true;

    });

    while (true)
    {
        if (running)
        {
            cv::imshow("window", image);
            cv::waitKey(1);
        }
    }

    task.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Without looking very deeply into it, I see problems.  `task` needs access to `running`. (Does this actually compile?) Importantly `running` must be declared as `std::atomic<bool>`.  Rather than  using `cv.imshow`, tryi showing the picture using the GUI. I am not up to linking this up with opencv. You'll have a much better chance of getting help if you post a [MCVE] .

Comment: Actually I've tried my best to create MCVE from a very long code and this is what I've come up with. And yeah, it compiles. I thought it's ok to access global variables from thread.

Comment: I will read to about `std::atomic` now. Thank you!

Comment: Also, relax that `while (true)` loop by adding an `else` to `if (running)` that calls `std::this_thread::yield();`  -- for starters. Once you get it limping along, we might discuss the possibility of doing the whole thing a better way.

Comment: Ah ha. I just now figured out that "the GUI" refers to `highgui.` I was assuming you were using something like Qt or wxWidgets. Ignore what I said about "showing the picture using the GUI."

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you expect the code to behave like. In particular what you want the background thread to do. As it is, it just waits some time and then changes a flag, apparently for no further reason. Anyhow, your interpretation that `sleep_for()` doesn't behave as documented is surely a misinterpretation. That leads us to a problem with your question, namely that you present an interpretation instead of observable facts.

Comment: Not sure what the point of that thread is here, but having `waitkey` inside the mouse event handler seems like asking for trouble -- `waitkey` runs the message loop, so ends up calling `onMouse` for mouse events. Good potential for infinite recursion. There's also no need for even the `imshow` in the event handler. You already update the global `image`, and constantly draw `image` in the `while` loop.